# Discontinuity in graphs but no discontinuity in data in plotting dataframes using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot predictions using scikit-learn, pandas, and matplotlib.
I'm able to predict the data and able to save them in dataframes. But now when I plot them there are two cases.

#### 1st case

I created a new column for the forecast predictions and plot them with the values i predicted from
`Adj. Close` is my feature and `forecast` are my predictions. As you can see the dates are matched perfectly so there shouldn't be any gaps.

My data:

```
            HL_Precentage  Adj. High  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume  \
Date                                                                      
2016-08-19       0.545879     801.23    796.88      799.65    1120763.0   
2016-08-22       0.625685     799.30    794.33      796.95     853365.0   
2016-08-23       0.629405     801.00    795.99      796.59     917513.0   
2016-08-24       0.973747     798.46    790.76      793.60    1284437.0   
2016-08-25            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN   
2016-08-26            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN   
2016-08-27            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN   
2016-08-28            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN   
2016-08-29            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN   
2016-08-30            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN          NaN 

  

             label    Forecast  
Date                            
2016-08-19  802.79         NaN  
2016-08-22  801.23         NaN  
2016-08-23  803.08         NaN  
2016-08-24  800.71         NaN  
2016-08-25     NaN  797.835059  
2016-08-26     NaN  799.896814  
2016-08-27     NaN  802.552861  
2016-08-28     NaN  798.483859  
2016-08-29     NaN  795.999011  
2016-08-30     NaN  797.866796
```

[image: Image Link: red is Adj. Close and blue is forecast]

(red is `Adj. Close` and blue is forecast)

#### 2nd case

To get rid of the gap I plugged the values of predictions in the `Adj. Close` column only and to my amusement the graph was a continuous one.

Data:

```
            HL_Precentage  Adj. High  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume  \
Date                                                                      
2016-08-19       0.545879     801.23    796.88  799.650000    1120763.0   
2016-08-22       0.625685     799.30    794.33  796.950000     853365.0   
2016-08-23       0.629405     801.00    795.99  796.590000     917513.0   
2016-08-24       0.973747     798.46    790.76  793.600000    1284437.0   
2016-08-25            NaN        NaN       NaN  796.877634          NaN   
2016-08-26            NaN        NaN       NaN  799.448407          NaN   
2016-08-27            NaN        NaN       NaN  801.340352          NaN   
2016-08-28            NaN        NaN       NaN  798.130538          NaN   
2016-08-29            NaN        NaN       NaN  794.900353          NaN   
2016-08-30            NaN        NaN       NaN  796.483742          NaN   

             label  Forecast  
Date                          
2016-08-19  802.79       NaN  
2016-08-22  801.23       NaN  
2016-08-23  803.08       NaN  
2016-08-24  800.71       NaN  
2016-08-25     NaN       NaN  
2016-08-26     NaN       NaN  
2016-08-27     NaN       NaN  
2016-08-28     NaN       NaN  
2016-08-29     NaN       NaN  
2016-08-30     NaN       NaN
```

[image: Image Link: red line is for Adj. close]

My question is how to make my first graph continuous so as to make my predictions not discontinuous?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the line to be continuous the data needs to overlap or a continuous series from 1 column. an easy way to do this would be to replace NA's in Forecast by adj close before plotting such has:

```
df['Adj. Close'].fillna(df.Forecast, inplace=True).plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a discontinuity in your data - the last `Adj. close` value was recorded on 08/24 and the first `Forecast` value is for 08/25.

In order to have no breaks in the line you would need the ends of your two series to overlap by at least one timepoint. You could, for example, compute a `Forecast` for 08/24 where you also have an `Adj. close` value.